# undefined reference to std::ostream::operator<<(__float128) when using g++ with -mlong-double-128

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, precision

I have the following small C++ code in a file called test.cc:

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
  long double x = 3.3;
  std::cout << x << std::endl;
}
```

Compiling in the normal way (simply g++ test.cc) works fine.

However, when trying with the -mlong-double-128 option there is a linking problem:

```
$ g++ -mlong-double-128 test.cc 
/tmp/cccKog5D.o: In function `main':
test.cc:(.text+0x1f): undefined reference to `std::ostream::operator<<(__float128)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I tried adding -lquadmath but the problem remains.

I tried this with g++ versions 5.4.0 and 6.1.0 with the same behavior for both.

It is possible to workaround the problem by casting to double whenever using the << operator, but I would really like to make it work without doing that. (The background is that I have a larger research code that I would like to be able to compile with -mlong-double-128 to get higher precision throughout, but it fails due to this issue.)

Any ideas on how to solve this?

EDIT:

Now I found that recompiling the libstdc++ library with -mlong-double-128 as suggested by @Niall solves the linking problem.

I downloaded the libstdc++ source code (part of the gcc-6.1.0.tar.gz package) and configured it as follows:

```
../configure --enable-cxx-flags=-mlong-double-128 --prefix=/home/elias/slask/inst --disable-multilib
```

Then, using the resulting libstdc++.a library file I can build my test.cc program without any linking errors:

```
g++ -mlong-double-128 test.cc /home/elias/slask/inst/lib64/libstdc++.a
```

However, when running the resulting executable it anyway gives wrong results, it prints "nan" instead of 3.3 as it should. It seems like it is calling some glibc routine to do the actual conversion to a string, which does not work because glibc was not compiled with -mlong-double-128. I tried recompiling glibc with -mlong-double-128 but that does not seem to work.

EDIT 2:

I fount this related issue in the GCC bugzilla pages:

[Bug 43622 - Incomplete C++ library support for __float128](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=43622)

Judging from the comments there it seems what I'm trying to do is probably not going to work right now, but may work in future versions, at least it's a known issue.

Comment: There's no need to write cast each time you output anything, since you can add an `ostream& operator << (ostream&, _float128)` and do the cast internally. But agree that there should be some way to do this with no workarounds

Comment: Thanks @alexeykuzmin0 yes that would be a better way, then I could get away without code changes in many places. I'll try it and see how it goes.

Comment: Was the/your standard library also compiled with `-mlong-double-128`? Given this affects the ABI, you may need to look into that (https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/x86-Options.html#index-mlong-double-128-2863)

Comment: @Niall no I have not compiled the C++ standard library myself, just using what comes with g++ on my Ubuntu computer. I have never tried compiling a C++ standard library myself, maybe I will need to learn how to do that to solve this. Thanks.